# Stored procedure with referenced linkedserver

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, linked-server

I am fighting with stored procedure with referenced linkedserver. Linked server is accesible over internet via port forwarding - so no VPN, LAN.

Servers are on both sides **MS SQL SERVER 2008 EE v. 10.0.5512**

Configurations Linked server, DTC:

cannot insert images yet:(

```
enable promotion of distributed transaction = false
RPC = false
RPC out = false

Network DTC Access checked
Allow inbound true
Allow outbound true
No authentication Required
```

Stored procedure looks like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSynchronizeArticles] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
(
    @pDebug bit,
    @siteId bigint
)
AS
BEGIN

  SELECT *
  FROM [LinkedServer].[MyDatabase].dbo.Storages 
  WHERE Storage.siteId = @siteId

  RETURN 0

END
```

As you can see no transaction here. If I am correct the MS DTC is creating transaction every time when the linked server is called.

I am calling this procedure from c# like this

```
  SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spSynchronizeArticles");
  sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDebug", false);
  sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteId", siteId);

  SqlParameter returnValue = new SqlParameter("returnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
  returnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
  sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(returnValue);

  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Context.LocalData.ConnectionString))
  {
    try
    {
      try
      {
        conn.Open();
        sqlCmd.Connection = conn;
        sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();

        return Convert.ToInt32(returnValue.Value);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        //log exception to file
        return -1;
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      conn.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

This c# code is called in infinite while to synchronize data. In same Thread and while there is also another method called which is getting data from file (if any exist) and saving them to local DB.

The SynchronizeArticles method is invoking more often and everything is working, but once the method for getting data from file is called, the SynchronizeArticles always throw this exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): MSDTC on server
>   'LocalServer\SQLEXPRESS2008' is unavailable.

The method is using Transaction and looks like

```
public void FillDataFromViewWithTrans(DataTable dt, string wherePhrase)
    {
      dt.Rows.Clear();
      SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(String.Format(@"SELECT * 
FROM SomeView
{0}", String.IsNullOrEmpty(wherePhrase) ? String.Empty : "WHERE " + wherePhrase));


      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Context.LocalData.ConnectionString))
      {
        SqlTransaction trans = null;
        try
        {
          try
          {
            conn.Open();
            trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
            sql.Transaction = trans;
            sql.Connection = conn;

            SqlDataAdapter dA = new SqlDataAdapter(sql);

            dA.Fill(dt);

            trans.Commit();
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            trans.Rollback();
            //log exception to file
            return;
          }
        }
        finally
        {
          conn.Close();
        }
      }
    }
```

This is just illustration samples :)

Tell me what I am missing.

Additionally I have big troubles with the MS DTC with various errors

1. From C# code when some users calls the procedure manually they sometimes got exception:

> The operation could not be performed because the OLE DB provider
>   'SQLOLEDB' was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

1. When I put the begin distributed transaction inside the stored procedure I got:

> Warning: Fatal error 8510 occurred at Apr 10 2013  9:07AM. Note the
>   error and time, and contact your system administrator.

What only helps is the restart of the windows service or the UI application. From the **MS SQL management studio** the procedure **works all the time** without problems.

Now I must say I am desperate, what am I missing?

**Edit:**

```
int i = 0;
      while (true)
      {
        i++;
        if ((i % 9) == 0)
        {
          //local select with transaction Works all the time
          CallLocalSelectWithTransaction(); 
        }

        // CallProcedure works 8 times, after first calling of CallLocalSelectWithTransaction
        // the callProcedure works no more.

        CallProcedure(); // procedure with linked server
      }
```

Comment: About the error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): MSDTC on server 'server_name' is unavailable." - you should enable DTC for remote access - check out this [article](http://www.techdreams.org/microsoft/aspnet/how-to-fix-msdtc-on-server-server-name-is-unavailable-erroraspnetsql-server/311-20080912)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I have the DTC enable for remote access and everything works. But when I call another c# code with transaction then next calling of stored procedure throws exception MSDTC on server ...
The only way to make it works is not use transactions in code at all (I am doing this for now), but this is really bad way to go.

Comment: I found out tool that you can test DTC - [Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;293799) and for [firewall check](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;q306843&).

Comment: Firewall should be turn off, I check that again. See my edit for code simulating the using of methods. As you can see the procedure runs 8 times OK, so the MS DTC must be running.